# Node logging unexpected UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous

I have a piece of code that's causing Node to log UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning.  But I'm not sure why.  Here's the code boiled down:

```
export class Hello {
  async good(): Promise<string> {
    let errorP = this.throwError();
    let responseP = this.doSomething();
    let [error, response] = await Promise.all([errorP, responseP]);
    return response + '123';
  }

  async bad(): Promise<string> {
    let errorP = this.throwError();
    let responseP = this.doSomething();
    let response = (await responseP) + '123';
    let error = await errorP;
    return response;
  }

  private async throwError(): Promise<string> {
    await (new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)));
    throw new Error('error');
  }

  private async doSomething(): Promise<string> {
    await (new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)));
    return 'something';
  }
}
```

Calling `try { await hello.bad(); } catch (err) {}` causes node to log UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Calling `try { await hello.good(); } catch (err) {}` does NOT log the warning

Full error:

```
(node:25960) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: error
    at Hello.<anonymous> (C:\hello-service.ts:19:11)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\hello-service.ts:5:58)
    at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:58:5)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:523:9)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(node:25960) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()
. To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:25960) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
{"level":30,"time":1639745087914,"pid":25960,"hostname":"AZWP10801-12","reqId":"req-1","dd":{"trace_id":"2081604231398834164","span_id":"2081604231398834164","service":"@amerisave/example-service","version":"0.0.0"},"res":{"statu
sCode":200},"responseTime":1025.4359999895096,"msg":"request completed"}
(node:25960) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
```

Some dependency versions:
node ver. 14.16.1
ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.8
ts-node ver. 9.1.1
typescript ver. 4.5.2

Why is `good` good, but `bad` bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in `bad()` is because the `errorP` promise rejects BEFORE you get to `await errorP` and thus it rejects when there is no reject handler for it in place.  Nodejs detects that a promise rejected and your process gets back to the event loop and that rejected promise does not have a reject handler on it.  That gets the "unhandled rejection" warning.

Notice here that while `await errorP` doesn't directly apply a reject handler, it does tie errorP to the parent `async` function which does have a reject handler on it, so the `await errorP` indirectly assigns reject handling to `errorP`.  Whereas `errorP` by itself will just reject and not cause anything to happen to the parent `async` function.  It will just be a variable containing a now rejected promise with no reject handler on it.

To take advantage of `async` automatic error propagation of rejected promises, you have to `await` that promise.

Nodejs doesn't know you're going to add the `await` in the future with code that will execute some time in the future, so it will report the unhandled rejection.

Code becomes subject to these types of errors where you put a promise into a variable and you have no reject handler on that promise of any kind and then you go `await` on some other promise BEFORE you ever put any sort of reject handler on that previous promise.  The promise is just sitting there with no error handling on it.  If, due to the timing of things, it happens to reject in that state, you will get the warning.  The usual solutions are:

1. Immediately put error handling on the promise so it's never left sitting by itself.
2. Don't create the promise until you're ready to use it however you're going to use it with appropriate error handling (with a `.then().catch()` or in a `Promise.all().catch()` or in an `await` or whatever).
3. Don't `await` other promises while a promise is sitting in a variable without any reject handling.

I find that if I can avoid putting a promise with no handling on it into a variable at all and rather just create the promise right into the circumstance where it's going to be monitored for completion and error, you don't even have to generally think about this issue.

---

FYI, you can illustrate the same general concept of a promise rejecting before you add a reject handler in a simpler manner here if you run this in nodejs:

```
function bad(t) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(reject, t);
    });
}

const b = bad(500);

// this timer will fire after bad() rejects
setTimeout(() => {
    b.catch(err => {
        console.log("caught b rejection");
    })
}, 600);
```

You will get the "uncaught rejection" error because when the promise rejects, it does not yet have a `.catch()` handler.  Your code has this same issue (though obscured a little more) because the reject handler comes from the `await` and the `async` function and the `try/catch` the caller of the `async` function is using.

Comment: Could you provide solution on provided example? Have similar problem with multiple awaits in function where later await is dependent on former awaits. Code propagates error to upper function but jest tests report having left open handles and also get UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning.

Comment: @malibeg - The general solution is to not ever create a promise that doesn't already have a `.catch()` handler of some kind immediately on it.  I'd have to see your code to know how to help you as this kind of stuff is very specific to your precise code.  Why don't you post your code and situation in your own question.  If you want me to take a look at it, just drop me a comment on your question with @ jfriend00 in it to bring my attention to it.

Comment: code is similar to given example in question just have more nested functions and should handle exception in top function.

Comment: @malibeg - I don't know what you expect from me here.  Show me your code in your own question and I can advise how to fix YOUR code.  Otherwise, don't EVER put a plain promise into a variable that doesn't already have a `.catch()` handler on it.  That's the only generic advice I can offer.  How to fix your specific code depends on your specific code.  I'm happy to help you in your question when/if you post your code in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hypothesis (that can be experimentally proven).

The difference in behavior between `good` and `bad` can be explained by the order of `await`s.

In `bad` you're awaiting on `throwError` after you have awaited on `doSomething`, while in `good`, you're awaiting on `Promise.all`, which will not return until both are fullfilled or at least one is rejected (which will be the case here).

So in `bad`, the throwing is happening *outside* of `await`, and your `catch` is not triggered, and it is caught internally by node.

If you change your `bad` so that you `await` on `throwError` first, then your catch will get triggered:

```
async bad(): Promise<string> {
    let errorP = this.throwError();
    let responseP = this.doSomething();
    let error = await errorP;
    let response = (await responseP) + '123';
    return response;
  }
```

Comment: So does this mean if I have multiple promises, I have to await them all before I can start processing the output of any of them?

Comment: Your suggested code fix just exposes the `responseP` promise to same error.  If it rejects before `errorP` resolves or rejects, you will just get the unhandled rejection on `responseP`.  So, while this makes the error go away for this hard coded sequence, it is not a general solution to the problem. See my answer for general solutions.

Comment: Yes, you're correct it was only for this case, where `responseP` never rejects. The main point was that if it throws outside of (or as you've said "before" - which might be a better term) the `await`, it's not going to be caught.